# Rerun function from callback

Tags: node.js, postgresql, loopbackjs

Here is my pseudo code:

```
Model.observe('after save', function (ctx, next) {
  const sql = `
    BEGIN TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
    -- ...
    COMMIT;
  `
  ds.connector.query(sql, function (err, res) {
    if (err) {console.log(err); return next(err)}
    next()
  })
}
```

I ttry to run a raw sql statement, but the db (postgres) return s with error:

> code: '40001',
>
> detail: 'Reason code: Canceled on identification as a pivot, during write.',
>
> hint: 'The transaction might succeed if retried.',

so if `err` is raised in `ds.connector.query` I want to rerun `ds.connector.query` instead of sending back the error in `Model.observe` function's callback (`next`)

Answer (score 0):

Not recommended since it can keep in an infinite loop, but it should works using recursive:

```
let failCount = 0, maxTry = 3;

Model.observe('after save', function (ctx, next) {
  const sql = `
    BEGIN TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
    -- ...
    COMMIT;
  `
  query(sql, next);
}

function query(sql, next) {
    ds.connector.query(sql, function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            if (failCount < maxTry) {
                query(sql, next); //querying again
                failCount++;
            } else {
                next(err);
            }
        }
        next()
    });
}
```

Comment: but I could you some variable, to keep track how many times it has benn rerun, could not I?